# refer to the id of an element

Tags: javascript, html

I have several links to play videos in a player with javascript. What would be the best way to refer to the id of the player from the link to make these links accessible and syntactically correct? It would be similar to using the for attribute in a label element.

```
    <a href="video" rel="playerid">video</a>
    <a href="video" data-playerid="playerid">video</a>
    <a href="video" itemref="playerid">video</a>
```

Comment: href is an example to not put a Youtube url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second one, using the [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes):

```
<a href="video" data-playerid="playerid">video</a>
```

I don't believe your first example using `rel` works if the player ID varies, because although you [can add to](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#other-link-types) the [list of valid values](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes) (thank you for pointing that out!), the `rel` still expresses the *kind* of relationship (e.g., `rel="icon"` or `rel="canonical"`), not the ID of something (which is the URI in the `href`).

Your third one uses a custom attribute without a `data-` prefix, making the HTML invalid.

So I think the second one, the `data-*`, is the way to go.

Comment: it's not really an answer to question he's asking, is it?

Comment: @WTK: I *thought* it was what was being asked. What do you think he's asking?

Comment: "What would be the best way to refer to the id of the player from the link to make these links accessible and syntactically correct?" You don't answer that, at least not in a direct way. You just explained the code he pasted.

Comment: @WTK: How is it helpful to just quote the question? I read the question. I read it twice, in fact, concerned from your comment that I'd missed the point. Clearly we're **interpreting** it differently. What would be helpful would be to tell me what your *interpretation* is, not just repeat what's already written. My interpretation is that the OP is asking which of the three alternatives to use (presumably open to others as well).

Comment: Anyone is free to edit the microformats wiki existing-rel-values page at any time to add a type. Extension types must be specified with the following information:
[4.12.5.14 Other link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#other-link-types)

Comment: @poselab: Cool, that's interesting! I wonder how well supported it is. Did I interpret your question right, btw?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In my opinion question is clear, what is the best way to link to video player to keep the link semantically correct. You're not answering that, just explaining line by line what attributes are there, without stating which and why you think is best to create such a link.

Comment: @WTK: I very clearly say I think the second one is best, and very clearly say why. (The OP's comment above argues another way, though.) Sorry, I'm just not getting you...?

Comment: @poselab: You mean option 1 (with `rel`), right? What is `playerid`. Do you intend that text, literally, in `rel`? Or would it vary from player to player?

Comment: it vary from player to player.

Comment: @poselab: Then I don't think you can use `rel`, updated the answer. Thanks again for the `rel` editing link (no pun).

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this

```
<a href="/js_error.html" onclick="Play('id'); return false;">...</a>
```

This is usually my preferred method of mixing javasript and links. If something fails with js on user end, the error page will be shown. The "return false;" bit should keep you on the page, as long as the Play() function executes properly. In my experience this is a durable and compatible way of handling such matters.

Regards